# outofmemory Exception for Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider if using obfuscated libraries

Tags: redis, out-of-memory, obfuscation

I want to use the Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider as a session cache provider for an asp.net application. I have to use some obfuscated libriares in my application. Once I add them, I get an out-of-Memory exception. The Cache works if I remove the references to those libraries. The exception occurs immediately after global.asax application_start. Maybe directly before or on session_start.

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="LocationNewsCache">   <providers>
    <add name="LocationNewsCache" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="link to AWS ElastiCache"
      port="6379" accessKey="" ssl="false" throwOnError="true"/>   </providers> </sessionState>
```

the error marks the "add Name" line as red and states it as System.OutOfMemoryException

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any implementation in your global.asa? Post the code here! Do you connection with Redis Server is ok? Change provider version Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.